# What performance can be expected from chemical rockets under Venusian atmospheric conditions?

Tags: rockets, engines, venus, specific-impulse

Is it feasible to use either solid or bipropellant liquid rocket engines to lift off from the surface of Venus?

"Reference datum" [air pressure on Venus is around 9.3 MPa](http://www.braeunig.us/space/atmvenus.htm); even on the top of, say, [Maat Mons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maat_Mons), the pressure 
would be around 5 MPa. Some modern engines have chamber pressures above 20 MPa (e.g. SSME, [RD-170](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-170)), so it seems 
possible for a rocket engine to work.

The [shuttle SRBs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Solid_Rocket_Booster) produce [substantially less pressure, around 4.3 MPa](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19910018886.pdf); **is it practical to get a solid rocket 
booster up above 10MPa?**

Due to the very high ambient pressure, I'd expect the expansion nozzle to be short and specific 
impulse to be poor. **Can the performance specifications of a liquid bipropellant rocket engine optimized to exhaust 
into pressures from 1 to 5 MPa, using similar turbomachinery to an existing engine, be estimated?** Ideally I'd like to get an estimate of the specific impulse curve of such an engine from 10 MPa to 0.1 MPa ambient.

Feel free to handwave away the thermal issues involved in maintaining liquid propellant tankage while waiting to launch from the [Searing Black Calm](https://larryniven.fandom.com/wiki/Becalmed_in_Hell_(short_story)). The goal here is to be able to simulate a rocket ascent from the surface of Venus to stable orbit, in order to answer [another question on the site](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39083/195).

I’m well aware this is not going to be the most practical way to ascend to orbit from Venus. I’m not asking if it’s optimal or practical. Please constrain discussion to rocket engines only.

[RPA](http://www.propulsion-analysis.com/RPA/download.htm) crashes promptly when I ask it to compute performance at 60 bar exit pressure.

Comment: I looked quickly at cutting off an SSME nozzle because I had those curves...turns out that the SSME is right about 10 MPa *at the throat* so a stub nozzle indeed. For exit plane pressure of 1.7 MPa the specific impulse would be around ... 100.

Comment: Yikes! That's gonna leave a mark on payload fraction.

Comment: Maybe the SSME is a bad choice? This is out of my wheelhouse.

Comment: I mean, it's not an ideal booster engine at sea level...

Comment: @OrganicMarble The SSME is probably about as good a choice as any. Its expansion ratio is optimized for near-sea-level pressure, and that I know of, nobody has built an engine for an exit pressure much greater than sea level pressure. For sure, to operate at Venus's surface you'd have to reduce the throat diameter to drive up the chamber pressure — which will also drive up the throat temperature, pressure, and heating, so you'd better be ready to design a regenerative cooling system that carries away more heat than the SSME's. It's better to loft by balloon first, then light up at altitude.

Comment: ISTR SSME exit plane pressure matched about 50k ft but I take  your point.

Comment: @TomSpilker The constraints of the question I'm working toward don't allow for balloon lift; I'm willing to drive to the top of a mountain near the Venusian equator but that's it.

Comment: The structural limit on a chamber is the _gauge_ pressure: the amount above ambient. So a chamber on Venus can still be the same pressure above ambient as on Earth.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Yep! From my experience at JPL, sometimes the question-askers, when they have a favorite approach in mind, pose the question in such a way as to rule out the obvious best approach.

Comment: @BobJacobsen Yes. But given a propellant chemistry, the axial temperature profile through the chamber and the throat is a function of the *absolute* pressures, so increasing the chamber and throat pressures will increase the down-chanber and throat temperatures. That's why I mentioned the cooling system, not the structural design.

Comment: @TomSpilker In StackExchangeSpeak that might be called the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The existence of several organisms that use water-jet propulsion in an even denser environment shows rockets can fundamentally still work. They will indeed be greatly impaired in performance, and you will also have huge problems with atmospheric drag...you will have to keep airspeeds ~50 times lower to keep your vehicle from breaking up. It's going to be a much longer and slower climb, and that's something rockets aren't good at. You've ruled out balloon lift, what about turbojets or rotors?

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I’ve added a paragraph to clarify that non rocket solutions are out of scope for this question. There are several QAs about other strategies for Venusian ascent on the site.

Comment: I am thinking the only way this could be remotely practical is with an aerospike nozzle - I tried doubling the SSME Pc with a conventional nozzle and it was still terrible performance. I'm trying to gen up up some numbers for an "ASSME" - no spaces in the acronym please - but not sure where I will end up.

Comment: Yeah, aerospike or some other altitude compensating nozzle came to mind also. For what it’s worth, the dynamic pressure constraints are pointing towards many stages of short burn time, so engines optimized for intermediate narrow pressure ranges are also potentially interesting.

Comment: just fyi the bounty [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39083/12102) expires in about 23 hours, and there's a [24 hour grace period after that](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/877/12102).

Comment: @BobJacobsen The relevant quantity for the mechanical load on the chamber wall is the pressure /difference/. If you want to generate the same pressure ratios, your pressure differences will be exorbitant.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Are combined cycle rockets allowed? E.g. a rocket engine that drives a turbine, which drives a fan, which propels the aircraft.

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi If you want to spec such an engine, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I happen to work (remotely, from half a wold away) at one of the two non-secret labs in the world that have running combined cycle engine prototypes. When I get to see my colleagues again, I can ask them how outlandish the idea is. John Bossard is involved with the other known prototypes, maybe you can ask a question on his blog: https://plasmawind.typepad.com/